# How to access a jQuery variable outside script?

Tags: jquery

I am an absolute newbie to jquery. So this might be a very basic question, please bear with me.

I have defined a jQuery function, which creates a 2-d array.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/testdata.txt',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                    var datatable = [];
                            // Populate datatable[]. This is a 2-d array.
                            $('#myTestDiv').text(datatable[2][0]);
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('error!');
                        }
                    })
                });
    </script>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
```

Now, I want to print the 2-d array, "datatable", in the HTML table, preferably with JSTL. But it appears that the "datatable" variable is not accessible outside . I know that the table is being populated correctly, the `$('#myTestDiv').text(datatable[2][0]);` is printing expected output.

How to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `var` from in front of the variable declaration. This will result in the variable being placed on the global `window` object, making it accessible from all over. Be careful with this type of practice though, as polluting your global context is frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I tried removing `var`, but no change in the output.

Comment: Show us how you're trying to access that variable. You're not trying to access it before the success method on the ajax request is even ran, are you? It doesn't exist until then.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should declare the `datatable` variable outside the `.ajax()` function so that it is visible in other parts of the code.

If you know it's being populated correctly, then it's just a scoping problem.

**UPDATE**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var datatable = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: '/testdata.txt',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                    var lines = data.split('\n');
                    $.each(lines, function(i, val) { 
                        datatable[i] = [];
                    });
                    $.each(lines, function(j, val) { 
                        datatable[j] = lines[j].split(',');
                    });
                    $('#myTestDiv').text(datatable[2][1]);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('error!');
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. By `you should declare the datatable variable outside the .ajax() function`, where should I declare the variable? Outside of any jQuery function, but within <script></script> tags, or outside of everything?

Comment: If you put it outside the script tags, would it be JavaScript?

Comment: Updated my answer to explain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply RET. I tried this, but it is still not working. As someone has pointed out here that I might be accessing the variable before its getting populated. Is that the case? If it is, how to avoid that? Sorry for too many questions, but I barely know jquery/ajax.

Comment: Well, I presume the processing you speak of is called inside the success function, where your `$('#myTestDiv').text(datatable[2][1]);` line is currently. To reach that line, the ajax call must have completed. If it's outside the .ajax() call, then yes, you'll have timing problems.

Comment: @RET, now i am sure i have some timing problems. if i show you the code, can you suggest some way?

Answer (score 0):

You could make `datatable` be a global variable so it's available anywhere, but that usually isn't what really makes a correct implementation because the rest of your code doesn't know when the data is in that variable.  The ajax function is asynchronous so you can't just assume  the data is in `datatable` after your ajax function runs.  In fact, it won't actually be available until some time later when the success handler is called.

Instead, a typical implementation is to call a function from your success function and pass it the datatable variable as an argument.  This solves both the timing (of the asynchronous ajax call) issue and the availability of the data issue (passed as an argument to a function).  That would look like this:

```
            success: function(data) {
                var datatable = [];
                // Populate datatable[]. This is a 2-d array.
                // call function to process the data
                processData(datatable);

            },
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you can access the **datatable** variable in JSTL. JSTL's role or action will be at the server side whereas the **datatable** is a client side javascript variable. 
What you can try is, assign this **datatable** value to a hidden bean property with `$('elementId').val(datatable)` and then access it at the server side in further requests to server